# Passing Javascript Click counts to php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I wrote a javascript click count its working properly but i want it to pass a single click to an external php script so as to insert the click and the id into db, it redirect a person to deals.php once a click is made on "click me" href and counts ,this is my code: Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
function linkClick()
{
document.getElementById('234').value = ++clicks;
}

document.write('<a href="deals.php?name=" + ++clicks;  
onclick="linkClick()">Click Me!</a>');
</script>
```

You have clicked the link  times.`enter code here`

Comment: You need to learn about ajax

Comment: Aren't you already passing this value to PHP when they click the link?  In the `name` query string value?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Maybe my low JS interactions but shouldn't the `onclick="linkClick()">Click Me!</a>'` be concatenated and quoted?

Answer (score 0):

You Can done it by using php only

on HTML Page

```
<?php 
 $query=mysql_query("select clickCount from click_count");
 $result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
 $clickCount=result['clickCount '] // get the value from database ?>
 <a href="deal.php?name=<?php echo ($clickCount+1);?>" >click me</a>
```

on deal.php Page
let table name is click_count

```
$clickCount=$_GET['name'];
mysql_query("update click_count set clickCount = '".$clickCount."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not relay on client side to count the clicks. This should be done in PHP when the user clicks:

```
<a href="deal.php?id=234">Click me</a>
```

and then, on deal.php:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$clicksCount = getClicksCountForId($id);
setClicksCountForId($id, $clicksCount++);
```

get and set clicks count into database can be done like Shut proposed in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to simplify your code by doing everything on the PHP side and storing the clicks counter in $_SESSION. The first time it's going to be zero (`$_SESSION["clicks"] = 0;`), when user clicks the link, "deals.php" will be executed, and the value will be increased (and database updated), example :

**main.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( ! isset( $_SESSION[ "clicks" ] ) )  // FIRST TIME.
   $_SESSION[ "clicks" ] = 0;
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="deals.php">Click Me!</a>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['clicks'];?>"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**deals.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION[ "clicks" ]++;        // INCREASE COUNTER.
                                // <=== UPDATE DATABASE HERE.
header( "Location: main.php" ); // RETURN TO MAIN.PHP.
?>
```

If you create two files with the given names (main.php, deals.php) and paste previous codes, it will work like you want : every click will be stored in database.